# does this drawing style have any particular name?

Tags: drawing, posters, traditional-media, pencil

can somebody please tell me whether this drawing style has any particular name?
where can i learn this drawing style?
This is certainly some hindu traditional drawing style, but i dont know whether i has a specific name. I would like to know if this drawing system has a specific name so that i can lear it.
i am referring to the pencil/pen like drawing, in this poster, which is mirrored on both sides at the top.
which drawing style is it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such artwork is generally called line art or line drawing. However, the style of art resembles traditional henna tattoo designs which are quite popular in India and elsewhere.  If you are just looking for something to google I suggest [Indian henna tattoo designs](https://www.google.co.uk/search?biw=1920&bih=916&tbm=isch&sxsrf=ACYBGNTi3e16qdrg1KAu-l6UBI_blv1pZA%3A1570274587019&sa=1&ei=G32YXbJq5YOMuw_i2aoQ&q=indian+henna+tatoo+design&oq=indian+henna+tatoo+design&gs_l=img.3...27462.28351..28980...0.0..0.116.653.6j1......0....1..gws-wiz-img.AqWiEObF5A8&ved=0ahUKEwjy49XXgIXlAhXlAWMBHeKsCgIQ4dUDCAY&uact=5).

Edit: After a little more research, I believe the Hindi term for these is *mehndi*, although most English speakers will probably not know this. I didn't known it until I googled it! Wikipedia says the art form originated in the Arabian Peninsula.

Comment: thank you...probably you are right...when i think about it again, there are some designs which resembles mehndi...mehndi is very common in india...i think arabs got it from india..you are very helpful..thanks again...let me do further research about it...

Comment: i am upvoting ur answer...thanks for taking time to help..
i was very much captivated by the design..

NB: since i have less than 15 rep points my up-votes are not being shown..